# How to send to "Miscellaneous" notification channel?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

### Problem description

When I try to send a `Notification` in **Android O** I have to specify a `NotificationChannel` to send to.

If I use the old method (not setting up any channel) like this `NotificationCompat.Builder(this)`, the `Notification` will not be displayed.

The same is for an invalid channel like this `NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "invalid")` or `NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "")`.

When I send a notification through **Firebase Cloud Messaging** and have my application in the background with no *notification channel* specified, it will be a notification in the **"Miscellaneous"** channel.

When I try to do the same in the foreground above mentioned will not work and neither will creating a notification channel with the name *"Miscellaneous"* and id *"{package}.MISCELLANEOUS"* and then sending through it. When I do that what happens is the following:

[image: Screenshot from my app's settings]

### What I want to know

How do I send a notification without a channel like **FCM** does it, so it lands in the regular **"Miscellaneous"** channel?

### Examples of this working

As I mentioned above, it happens with the *FCM notifications*, but e.g. **Gmail** also uses the miscellaneous channel. **So how do I use it?**

[image: Screenshot of Gmail's notification channels]

I believe that they would have removed the miscellaneous channel if it is normally unusable.

### Shorter description

Why is this code not sending a notification to the "Miscellaneous" notification channel, it is in fact not sending any notification (only on Android O, the code works on lower Android versions).

```
(getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).notify(1, NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(URLDecoder.decode("Title", "UTF-8"))
                    .setContentText(URLDecoder.decode("Text", "UTF-8"))
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.color))
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT))
                    .build())
```

Comment: To create a notification channel:
    Construct a notification channel object with an ID that's unique within your package.
    Configure the notification channel object with any desired initial settings such as an alert sound, as well as an optional description visible to the user.
    Submit the notification channel object to the notification manager                  .https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Have you found a solution? Have you tried with the just released final Android 8 (vs. dev preview)?

Comment: @Arhimed I did not try with the final Android 8, I think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ID for that channel is `fcm_fallback_notification_channel`. The firebase-messaging library creates it internally.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/076c26db27dd54d809fb2ccff8593b64fb3db043/firebase-messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/messaging/CommonNotificationBuilder.java#L66

Comment: See Sca09's answer, because it's not always the case.

Comment: Thank you and I love u. Works with notifee.

Answer (score 7):

As it has been said in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45930522/6509751), the id of the default channel created by Android System is `fcm_fallback_notification_channel`, but be careful because the System doesn't create the channel until it has to manage the first push notification. So if you manage all notifications inside your extension of the `FirebaseMessagingService` class, it may happen that the channel doesn't exist and you run into errors like:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=fcm_fallback_notification_channel pri=-2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
```

My recommendation is to check if the default channel exists before creating the notification and create it if it doesn't exist:

```
private void createDefaultNotificationChannel() {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
     NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

     if (notificationManager.getNotificationChannel("fcm_fallback_notification_channel") != null) {
       return;
     }

     String channelName = getString(R.string.fcm_fallback_notification_channel_label);
     NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("fcm_fallback_notification_channel", channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
     notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```